# While trying to install jpeg library, sudo make install says it cannot create a directory or file

Tags: sudo

I ran the ./configure script successfully. Then make ran successfully (although I had to manually edit Makefile to remove ./ before libtool. Then make test passed, sudo make -n install had no problem but sudo make install says

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 jconfig.h /home/skh/jpeg/include/jconfig.h
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/home/skh/jpeg/include/jconfig.h': No such file or directory
Makefile:209: recipe for target 'install-headers' failed"
The jconfig.h file exists in the working directory.
```